# How do I validate if a string is valid Yelp URL in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Example Yelp URLs:

```
http://www.yelp.com/biz/benu-san-francisco-4
http://www.yelp.com/biz/coi-san-francisco
```

The last part is the **yelp_id**, which should be returned.  If the URL is invalid, the function should return null.

This is my implementation, but it's probably not the best way to write it.

```
function getYelpID(url){
    if(url.indexOf('yelp.com/biz/') >= 0){
        var sp = url.split('/');
        if(sp.length >= 3){
            return sp[sp.length - 1];
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with a better way to validate the YELP url and also return the ID?

Note: I'm sure some people will paste a URL that starts with "www" instead of "http".  I'm also assuming some people will paste "https" instead.  I want a function that works with all common scenarios (whatever they might be).  My function should work all scenarios, but it's definitely not the best way to do it.

Comment: Define "valid". Should it just match the pattern or should it actually resolve to an existing URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
function getYelpID(url) {
    var m=/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?yelp\.com\/biz\/([^\/]+)$/i.exec(str);
    return m ? m[1] : null;
}
```